# Question about "接する"

Tags: meaning

In this sentence :

> 接しているうち、彼女の魅力を感じせずにはいられません。

can I translate 接しているうち as "While getting to know her "?
(and then : " X cannot help but to feel her charm " ? )

So it would end up being : " If I/you get to know her, I/you won't be able but to feel her charm" ?

Or am I completely off? Also are there others words or (better) ways of saying : "To get to know someone" in Japanese?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a quote or you’re trying E->J translation?

Comment: "感じ**せ**ずには" <- It should be a typo of 感じずには...

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks, Chocolate, so the 例文 is bad? or atleast at that spot?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Anki deck full of 例文, after reverse googling it, I found this translation next to it : "Once you get to know her, you won’t be able to resist her charm."

Comment: Just that part. 「接しているうち、彼女の魅力を感じずにはいられません。」 would sound natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

接する literally means "to contact with ～", and 接する itself does not mean "to know". "To get to know her" is not entirely wrong at least in this context, but I think a closer translation is something like "to spend time with her" or "to speak with her".

Comment: @お星座 Hmm, 知り合う is a one-time event, so you cannot use it with うちに.